# ASP.NET MVC Model & Business Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, architecture, model

I am looking for some guidance on how to incorporate business rules into an asp.net mvc application and how they relate to the model.

First a little background so we know what kind of solutions are relative for this question.  At work we use WinForms, MVP, BusinessObjects, DataAccessObjects, and DataTransferObjects.  The boundaries of the layers use DTOs to send parameters to methods and as return types, or return List types.

Right now we are adding a facade layer to translate the DTOs into Domain Objects for the UI to work with, since the architect does not like how using DTOs in the PresentationLayer is working currently.  I am comfortable about all of this in theory aside from it being practical or not.

I am making a website for fun, but for considerations lets say it serves the same amount of traffic as SO, something like 60,000 hits a month last I heard.  I am comfortable with the mechanics of the controllers and the views, and how the model integrates with the two.

I am using NerdDinner as a sample for building the site and I follow the Repository pattern implementation in the examples.  What I don't get is how to incorporate business objects into the mix.

I hear people talk about LINQ as the DataAccessLayer/DataAccessObjects.  If I force all of my requests though the business objects as I am used to I have introduced some weird dependencies.  Both my UI and my BO have to know about my DAO.

What would kind of make sense is to use the LINQ classes as a true DAO layer, hide it behind the BO, and have the BO transform between POCO and LINQ objects.

My only concern there is I am fine with binding my UI to LINQ classes, and don't really need all the extra work, I am happy with a thin lightweight approach as in NerdDinner.

So what I have essentially is the Repository that is instantiated in the controllers that takes and return LINQ objects.  My business objects have static methods that just take LINQ classes and perform some calculation, say apply a certain states tax %, or w/e.

Since a lot of these calculations have to be done across the results of the repository I am thinking of combining them into one central area, like a facade layer, but one that just does transforms against the data and not translating to other objects sets (DomainObjects <-> DTOs).

Should I do that, or should I say that those business methods really are part of my model and that they should be in the repository methods that return the objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a design standpoint I would design it like this.  Of course naming is just for the purpose of this post you don't have to name your DAL and BLL ..Repository and ..Service.

Have repositories (or one) where your data access/queries should be happening.  It should ideally just contain queries (compiled or not).  I personally have a repository for each data type to help keep queries separated.

The next layer should be your business layer which I like to call services.  These classes are responsible for all logic regarding validation, prep steps and anything else needed to be done to get the consumer of the service the information it needs.  As with an ASP.NET MVC app I have my services return view models which are then directly passed into strongly-typed views.  With my services I usually group them logically together instead of one for each data type.

This is a great design because it keeps your data access code and presentation code nice and thin and most of the logic where things can go wrong is in your service (or business) layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think my primary concern is that both the PresentationLayer and the ServiceLayer have to reference the DataAccessLayer.  Also, I moved away from validation in Business objects or the PresentationLayer and instead do it directly on my model which is a direction I like.

Comment: But I do like the answer so +1